# Azure Pipelines status badge not getting displayed in markdown

Tags: github, azure-pipelines

I've set up azure pipelines for one of my github repositories. Everything is working perfect except the build status badge. It is not getting displayed correctly, it seems like the image could not be loaded.

This is currently getting displayed:

[image]

#### Edit

Code used in the markdown file is automatically generated by azure devops

```
[![Build Status](https://dev.azure.com/larsbehl/larsbehl/_apis/build/status/LarsBehl.llCompiler?branchName=master)](https://dev.azure.com/larsbehl/larsbehl/_build/latest?definitionId=1&branchName=master)
```

Comment: Please provide some kind of code.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Allow **anonymous access to badges** might be disabled for your project settings.

You can go to **Project Settings**, click **Settings** under **Pipelines**. And make sure toggle **Disable anonymous access to badges** is off. Please refer to below pic.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's the issue I was hitting. I had to first enable at the organization level; and then enable per project.

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: You sir/madam, are awesome.

Comment: To anyone having a hard time finding where to "Project Settings" is located. It's at the bottom-left corner of the project window.

Comment: may also have to adjust settings at an organization level.

Comment: The pipeline is connected to your repo and it cannot determine if your repo is allowed to show the badge? Where do you suppose to use the badge then if it's disabled for anonymous access?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to update this setting!

Go to "Organization Settings", then find "Pipelines" > "Setting"> "Disable anonymous access to badges"

Screenshot for reference: [Azure organization settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7Os7.png)

Comment: I'm upvoting this, since this is also part of the accepted solution: if your Org Settings disable this, the project settings are not going to allow you to override that setting.