# Does Github support anonymous access to workflow status badges for private repositories?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, salesforce, github-actions, confluence

These GitHub [workflow badges](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/adding-a-workflow-status-badge) that show the results of GitHub Actions display fine in e.g. the GitHub README.md or when pasted as the URL in a browser with a session hooked up to GitHub.

But when accessed from Confluence Cloud using the same URL (or from an incognito browser instance) GtHub returns a not found 404 which is not surprising.

Does GitHub have a setting such as the Azure one [Azure Pipelines status badge not getting displayed in markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674639/azure-pipelines-status-badge-not-getting-displayed-in-markdown) to make the badges public? I haven't found one so far.

(On Jenkins this option is called "Grant ViewStatus permissions for Anonymous Users".)

**PS**

Did some more Googling this morning and found:

- [Getting the status of a badge from a private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190387/getting-the-status-of-a-badge-from-a-private-repository)
- [Workflow/actions status badge giving 404 on private repo in an organization](https://github.community/t/workflow-actions-status-badge-giving-404-on-private-repo-in-an-organization/16242)

but the solution in the second link doesn't work for me.